# How to rewrite /foo to index.php?x=foo but also /foo/bar to index.php?x=foo&bar=true in one RewriteRule?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Using Apache's RewriteEngine, how to rewrite `/foo` to `index.php?x=foo` but rewrite `/foo/bar` to `index.php?x=foo&bar=true` in one `RewriteRule`?

I have this now:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)? index.php?x=$1 [L,NC] # rewrites /foo to index.php?x=foo, but not /foo/bar to index.php?x=foo&bar=true
```

This only rewrites `/foo` to `index.php?x=foo`, but not `/foo/bar` to `index.php?x=foo&bar=true`. How can I add that to the `RewriteRule`?

Comment: The general question is: how to do two rewrites in one RewriteRule?

Comment: Put simply, you can't achieve two rewrites with one RewriteRule.

Comment: So how would I go about this? Can I use two `RewriteRule`s without messing up the `RewriteCond`s?

Answer (score 2):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?x=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?x=$1&$2=true [L]
```

The first rule is to break if the requested URI can be mapped to an existing file or directory. Otherwise the other two rules are tested and applied if one of them matches the requested URI path.